# Print Enum value's Name in VBA

Tags: vba, enums, casting

*One of those times when you forget the basics (this .NET has corrupted all my VBA knowledge).*

How do I convert an integer to enum value and then get that enum value's name?

```
For i = 2 To 10
  Debug.Print CStr(CType(i, MsoAutoShapeType)) 'should print "msoShapeParallelogram" etc.
Next
```

This of course doesn't work. There is no `CType` in VBA (why did I think there was).

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks. The answer with the highest votes seems applicable, but I'd rather avoid filling the entire enum (180+ values) by hand.

Comment: I mostly meant "Parsing the VBA code yourself with the VBIDE Extensibility library is going to appear nice & simple at first".

Comment: Which is e.g. `set enum_info = TLI.TLIApplication.TypeLibInfoFromFile("full path to MSO.DLL")` and then loop over `enum_info.Members` looking for one where `Value` matches and taking its `Name`.

Comment: @GSerg: Ouch. There be dragons. Thanks anyway. For now I've used VSTO to copy the enum to Notepad++ and then used some regex to convert it to a VBA dictionary. I can now use the value of `I` to get its string name. It's working but I thought VBA would have something more elegant than that.